# Pointwise implies Uniform Convergence on infinite subset

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I came upon this statement in stack exchange. Can't remember where.

Statement :
If $f_n$ is a sequence of functions (not necessarily continuous) on $[0,1]$ such that $f_n$ converges point-wise to $0$, then there exists an infinite subset of $[0,1]$ where the convergence is uniform.

I couldn't prove it. I believe the claim is true because $[0,1]$ is uncountable but the set of sequences is countable only.

Any help would be appreciated in assistance to how to prove it.

Comment: A stronger statement is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorov%27s_theorem

Comment: @MartinR The functions have been assumed to be measurable in the wiki link you provided. Is it a required condition ?

Comment: You are right, that theorem can not be applied in the general case.

Comment: Crossposted at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397368/pointwise-convergence-imples-uniform-convergence-in-an-infinite-subset

Comment: The answer has been answered on Math Overflow. The link is https://mathoverflow.net/q/397368/318305